# Prove $A_q(3, 2) = q^2$ for all $q \ge 2$

Tags: coding-theory

Prove $A_q(3, 2) = q^2$ for all $q\ge 2$

I've tried using the sphere packing bound to find a max M for a (3, M, 2) code (with hamming distance 1), and found $M< {q^3\over 4q-3} < q^2$. I then tried the sphere packing bound again for some (3+1, M, 2+1) code and found $M \le {q^4 \over 4q - 3} > q^2$. My professor hasn't shown us any other method of calculating maximum M so I would greatly appreciate some guidance (Not necessarily the answer)

Edit: **Solution**

**Obtaining an upper bound for $A_q(3, 2)$:**
After @Jyrki Lahtonen told me about the Singleton bound, I found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_bound) that for some q-ary (3, M, 2)-code you can obtain a maximum bound for M using the inequality $$M \le q^{n-d+1}$$ In this case, we see that $M \le q^{3-2+1} = q^2$ so  $A_q(3, 2) \le q^2$

**Obtaining a q-ary $(3, q^2, 2)$ code:**
I started by declaring the $(2, q^2, 1)$ code $C = F^2$ and adding a checksum digit to each codeword of C (since the distance of C is 1). The result is a new code $C_1=(3,q^2, 2)$. By finding $C_1$, I've proven $A_q(3, 2) \ge q^2$. Thus $A_q(3, 2) = q^2$.

Comment: If $F$ is your alphabet field (or a ring), you could try to use the subset
$$C=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in F^3\mid x_1+x_2+x_3=0\}.$$ This should give you existence. You get optimality from an argument like Singleton bound: Show that no two distinct codewords can share the same two first components.

Comment: Kiitos paljon. I was able to finish the problem after you told me about the Singleton bound.

Comment: Good job, Collin! If you feel like doing that, I would like to encourage you to post your solution here as well as an answer. The software should allow you to do that (at least after a couple of hours?). That way you would get more feedback on your solution. And also welcome upvotes/reputation points that may come in handy, if you plan to visit the site regularly. Last but not least: Welcome to Math.SE!